# How do I prevent changes to properties of a property?

Tags: c#

I have a class named Class1 and In this class I have a property named MyProperty. In another class I declare Class1 property but I want in this situation MyProperty be readonly. How can I do this?

```
public class Class1
{
     public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
     public Class1 Class1Property { get; }
}

public class Class3
{
    void Method()
    {
        Class2 obj = new Class2();
        obj.Class1Property.MyProperty = 2;//I want this be illegal (In this place only)
    }
}
```

Comment: try `public int MyProperty { get; private set; }`

Comment: I want just in this place MyProperty be readonly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do some further abstraction and create an interface for `Class1`:

```
public interface IClass1
{
    int MyProperty { get; }
}
```

Then make `Class1` implement this interface:

```
public class Class1 : IClass1
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

`Class2` should not expose a `Class1` instance, but an instance of `IClass1`:

```
public class Class2
{
    public IClass1 Class1Property { get; }
}
```

Now you got the behaviour you want:

```
public class Class3
{
    void Method()
    {
        Class2 obj = new Class2();
        obj.Class1Property.MyProperty = 2; // Doesn't work.
    }
}
```

Comment: (Remark) `Class2` will require a backing field for `Class1Property`, which will need to be of type `Class1`. `Class2` has full access to the backing field, but the `Class1Property.get` will return the read-only interface.

Comment: Also, the interface approach could be circumvented with a type cast. 
`(obj.Class1Property as Class1).MyProperty = 2;`

Comment: That's allways the deal. However that's not the a good way to code. You should allways write code against interfaces.

Comment: Perhaps it's better to ask OP to clarify the purpose. That aside, I'm pointing out that there are three approaches to ReadOnly - (1) For initialize-once values, use `readonly` keyword. (2) For guarding against casual modifications, use a read-only interface as you demonstrated. (3) For situations where modification must be guarded against a malevolent user, use a read-only proxy object (a full class that wraps the original class.)

Answer (score 3):

`Class1` has decided that `MyProperty` is modifiable, no matter how you obtain a `Class1`, so what you want simply is not possible.

There are some ways that you can re-work your design, though. This is the approach I would take:

```
public class ReadOnlyClass1
{
    public int MyProperty { get; protected set; }
}

public class Class1 : ReadOnlyClass1
{
    public new int MyProperty {
        get { return base.MyProperty; }
        set { base.MyProperty = value; }
    }
}
```

Now, you can give `Class3` a property of type `ReadOnlyClass1`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this, the easiest as mentioned in the comments is by making the setter of "MyProperty" private:

```
public int MyProperty { get; private set; }
```

You can also try another access modifier that better suits your need.

Just think what the get and set mean: When being compiled, a Getter and Setter method gets created much like it was implemented in java.

You can also create the property with just a "get" and implement the "set" functionality outside of the property itself (like in the class constructor, in an internal method or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

```
public int myProperty{get;private set;}//this is read only property

obj.Class1Property.MyProperty = 2;//this is illegal
```